# In VSTS, can I bulk change the agent queue?

Tags: powershell, build, azure-devops

If I want to change all of my builds and releases to a new agent queue, is there a way to do that all at once?

The [Agent Queue API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/queues/overview) doesn't have anything about changing which queue is used, and the [Build API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#update-a-build) doesn't have a variable for the queue name. In VSTS, in the *Agent Pools* tab in settings, I can see a list of pools and the builds that were run on them, but I don't see a way of changing them.

Is there a programmatic way to change them all at once, or do I have to go through and change them all manually?

I'm experimenting on a specific build before fully implementing it in on every build. My program flow right now is: get the build definition, get the queue agent from a build that has the right one, set the queue in the old version equal to the new one, and PUT the whole thing back in VSTS.

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$result3 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri3 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$q = $result3.queue
$result.queue = $q
$result | ConvertTo-JSON
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT $uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType "application/json" -Body $result
```

I'm getting the error

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name:
```

How do I properly configure the PUT from the GET?

Comment: Do you solve the issue with my solution?

Comment: I did not, we're going through some maintenance and the build agents have been offline. I think ultimately I'm going to have to change the whole way build steps are made in the near future

Comment: Feel free to try it if you have time, just need to specify the API urls.

Answer (score 2):

The REST API can only change the agent queue for a certain build definition.

So you need to **get all the build definitions for a team project, and then loop to change the agent queue for the build definitions**. Details are below:

1. Get the id for the agent queue you want to apply for the build definitions

   Use the [get a list of queues](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/queues/overview#get-a-list-of-queues) REST API:

   ```
   GET https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/distributedtask/queues?api-version=3.0-preview.1
   ```

   In the listed agent queues, find the `id` of the agent queue you want to use.

   [image]

   Such as if you want to use `Default` agent, you can use the `id` as `7` in the following step.
2. [Get build definitions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-list-of-build-definitions) for a project

   ```
   GET ttps://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=2.0
   ```

   You can get each build definition’s definition `id`, `revision` and definition `name`.
3. Loop each build definition and change the agent queue. Updating build definition, it needs build revision and repository information. So you should to get the build definition repository by the [get a build definition REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-build-definition):

   ```
   GET https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/build/definitions/definitionID?api-version=2.0
   ```

   Then you can get repository information like:

   ```
   "repository": {
           "properties": {
               "cleanOptions": "0",
               "labelSources": "0",
               "labelSourcesFormat": "$(build.buildNumber)",
               "reportBuildStatus": "true",
               "gitLfsSupport": "false",
               "skipSyncSource": "false",
               "checkoutNestedSubmodules": "false",
               "fetchDepth": "0"
           },
           "id": "e89075b8-d7bd-4c3f-b24c-23276d89e8ec",
           "type": "TfsGit",
           "name": "vs2017",
           "url": "https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/Git2/_git/vs2017",
           "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/master",
           "clean": "true",
           "checkoutSubmodules": false
   }
   ```

   Then you can the [update build definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#update-a-build-definition) agent queue:

   ```
   PUT https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/build/definitions/definitionID?api-version=2.0

   Application/json as:
   {
     "id": 6,
     "revision": 356,
     "queue": {
           "id": 7
       },
        "repository": {
           "properties": {
               "cleanOptions": "0",
               "labelSources": "0",
               "labelSourcesFormat": "$(build.buildNumber)",
               "reportBuildStatus": "true",
               "gitLfsSupport": "false",
               "skipSyncSource": "false",
               "checkoutNestedSubmodules": "false",
               "fetchDepth": "0"
           },
           "id": "e89075b8-d7bd-4c3f-b24c-23276d89e8ec",
           "type": "TfsGit",
           "name": "vs2017",
           "url": "https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/Git2/_git/vs2017",
           "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/master",
           "clean": "true",
           "checkoutSubmodules": false
       }
   }
   ```

   Now build definitions in the current project are all changing the agent queues as the default agent (`id`=`7` as in the example). You can use a similar way to change other build/release definitions.

Comment: I updated the original post with some of my script. I was trying to do it more or less how you suggested, but I can't figure out the syntax for the JSON to update the build. I had also been using PATCH instead of PUT.

Comment: You'd better define a variable with the content for the PUT rest api body. And then get the parts  from GET rest api to replace the body variable.

Comment: So I have to create the whole build every time and reupload it? That will take a lot of time and is a lot of effort for just changing one variable. Is there no way to just run a PATCH and update one variable? If I have to create the whole build every time, it might make sense to just have the data for every build saved in a repository and then I can update them individually.

Comment: No, the PATCH method is not available for this rest api. You should use PUT method.

Comment: This is not currently sufficient. I actually just wrote something to do your exactly suggestion (before reading this post), but on update I lost some of my previous properties because the individual get was not able to get all details for the build. I'm left manually doing the updated of the build queue.

Comment: Update, you can actually do this with the REST API if you don't screw with wha tit returns to you. This was a fault I had in what I was working on. Once I did that, I was actually able to update the build queue successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer this code:

```
param(
[string]$uri,
[string]$uri3
)
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f 'test','XXX')))
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$result3 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri3 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
foreach($bd in $result.value){
 $detailbuild=Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri "$($bd.url)?api-version=2.0" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
  $detailbuild.queue=$result3
  $bdJson=$detailbuild| ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 20
  $updateDefUrl="$($bd.url)?api-version=2.0"
  Write-Host $bdJson
 $resultUpdaet= Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $updateDefUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType "application/json" -Body $bdJson
}
```

Arguments:`-uri 'https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/[project]/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=2.0&type=build' -uri3 'https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/[project]/_apis/distributedtask/queues/[queueid]?api-version=3.0-preview.1'`