# How to update VSTS release job agent pool using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, user-agent

I am trying to update VSTS release definition agent pool using powershell. Able to get the agent id and release definition details.

Powershell :

```
$User = 'xxxx@software.com'
$PersonalAccessToken = 'xxxx'
$base64authinfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f  $User, $PersonalAccessToken)))
$vstsAccount = "software"
$resource = 'Enterprise'

#Get the Agent ID
$uri = "https://$vstsAccount.visualstudio.com/_apis/distributedtask/pools/"
$projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authinfo)} | ConvertTo-Json
$projects = $projects | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host "Json Body :" $projects
$id = $projects.value | ? name -eq 'Hosted VS2017'
Write-Host "Agent Pool Id :" $id.id


#Get release definition details
$uri2 = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$vstsAccount/$resource/_apis/release/definitions/860?api-version=5.0"
$projects2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $uri2 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authinfo)} | ConvertTo-Json
$projects2 = $projects2 | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host "Json Body :" $projects2
```

Response  :

```
@{
source=userInterface; 
revision=84; 
description=; 
createdBy=; 
createdOn=2019-02-15T07:27:04.357Z; 
modifiedBy=; 
modifiedOn=2019-04-04T17:27:30.487Z; 
isDeleted=False; 
variables=; 
variableGroups=System.Object[]; 
environments=System.Object[]; 
artifacts=System.Object[]; 
triggers=System.Object[]; 
releaseNameFormat=Release-$(rev:r); 
tags=System.Object[]; 
pipelineProcess=; 
properties=; 
id=860; 
name=JMeterReleaseJob; 
path=\; 
projectReference=; 
url=https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/software/18979a9c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-f3fa4a82df3c/_apis/Release/definitions/860; _links=
}
```

Agent ID json :

```
"value":  [
                  {
                      "createdOn":  "2016-03-23T12:04:35.723Z",
                      "autoProvision":  true,
                      "autoSize":  true,
                      "targetSize":  null,
                      "agentCloudId":  null,
                      "createdBy":  null,
                      "owner":  null,
                      "id":  2,
                      "scope":  "3e93f9e6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-994d196e1121",
                      "name":  "Hosted",
                      "isHosted":  true,
                      "poolType":  "automation",
                      "size":  10
                  },
                  {
                      "createdOn":  "2017-03-21T00:40:47.527Z",
                      "autoProvision":  true,
                      "autoSize":  true,
                      "targetSize":  null,
                      "agentCloudId":  null,
                      "createdBy":  null,
                      "owner":  null,
                      "id":  4,
                      "scope":  "3e93f9e6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-994d196e1121",
                      "name":  "Hosted VS2017",
                      "isHosted":  true,
                      "poolType":  "automation",
                      "size":  10
                  },
                  {
                      "createdOn":  "2018-05-04T10:20:59.69Z",
                      "autoProvision":  false,
                      "autoSize":  true,
                      "targetSize":  null,
                      "agentCloudId":  null,
                      "createdBy":  "@{displayName=Kabir Sharan; url=https://spsprodweu3.vssps.visualstudio.com/A3e42757e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ee414eb0f5b1/_apis/Identities/8fe521c4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-6ca5f1b30c10; _links=; 
id=8fe521c4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-6ca5f1b30c10; uniqueName=Kabir@software.com; imageUrl=https://condecosoftware.visualstudio.com/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.OGZlNTIjhhLWFlZTgtNmNhNWYxY
jMwYzEw; descriptor=aad.OGZlNTIxYzQtYmQwNygtNmNhNWYxYjMwYzEw}",
                      "owner":  "@{displayName=Kabir Sharan; url=https://spsprodweu3.vssps.visualstudio.com/A3e42757e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ee414eb0f5b1/_apis/Identities/8fe521c4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-6ca5f1b30c10; _links=; id=8
fe521c4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-6ca5f1b30c10; uniqueName=Kabir@software.com; imageUrl=https://condecosoftware.visualstudio.com/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.OGZlNLWFlZTgtNmNhNWYxYjMwY
zEw; descriptor=aad.OGZlNTIxYzQtYmQwNy03MNmNhNWYxYjMwYzEw}",
                      "id":  10,
                      "scope":  "3e93f9e6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-994d196e1121",
                      "name":  "PaasAgent1",
                      "isHosted":  false,
                      "poolType":  "automation",
                      "size":  0
                  }]
```

Now i want to update agent pool in release definition.

Reference : 
[In VSTS, can I bulk change the agent queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650117/in-vsts-can-i-bulk-change-the-agent-queue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to modify the object returned when you invoke $uri2 then use the PUT HTTP method to update the release definition in Azure DevOps.

Converting $projects2 to and from JSON is unnecessary, the objects can be manipulated directly.  Remove `| ConvertTo-Json` from the end of the Invoke-RestMethod that sets $project2 and also the line `$projects2 = $projects2 | ConvertFrom-Json`.

To change the change the Agent Pool you'll need to update the queueId property of the relevant deploy phase in the relevant environment.  If you had 1 environment with 1 deploy phase this would by done by

```
$projects2.environments[0].deployPhases[0].deploymentInput.queueId = $id.id
```

If you have multiple environments and/or deploy phases you'll need to change the array keys on those properties accordingly.  Then convert the $projects2 object to JSON before sending the HTTP PUT request:

```
$body = $projects2 | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
$uri3 = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$vstsAccount/$resource/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=5.0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $uri3 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authinfo)} -Body $body -ContentType application/json
```

Comment: The property 'queueId' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: There is no queueid present in the response. i updated the question.

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"VS402982: A retention policy is not set for the stage ‘Stage 1’. Retention policies at the release pipeline level are deprecated. Use a retention 
policy at the stage level. If you are using the browser to access the service, refresh the browser cache by pressing Ctrl-F5 and try 
again.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException, 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data","typeKey":"InvalidRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Comment: queueId is a child property of the environments property.  The error above occurs when $body isn't converted to JSON correctly.  In your script you're converting the output from `Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $uri2 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authinfo)}` to JSON then back from JSON.  As I've mentioned in my answer this is unnecessary.  You only need call ConvertTo-Json once and that should be done once you've changed the value of queueId in $projects2.

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"No agent pool found with identifier 4.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskAgentQueueNotFoundException, 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi","typeKey":"TaskAgentQueueNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Comment: Ok the json of the agents i am getting is having id 4 corresponding to HostedVS 2017 but is it unable to find when i run code. Strange thing is when i give id equal to 10 then it set the HostedVS 2017 in agent pool. updating the agent pool json.

Comment: Your code is getting the id of the agent pool associated with your Azure DevOps organization.  What you need is the id of the queue associated with your project.  This documentation explains how to do that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/queues/get%20agent%20queues?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1